# Unable to create an audience on Parse

Tags: parse-platform, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, parse-android-sdk

I am trying to get my android app setup to send push notifications via Parse.

**build.gradle**

```
 compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.13.0'
```

**Application.java**

```
 //in onCreate
 Parse.initialize(this, "appId", "clientKey");
 ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
 <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />

 <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver">
     <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
     </intent-filter>
 </receiver>

 <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver"
        android:exported="false">
     <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
         <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
         <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />              
     </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
     <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
       <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="MY_APP_ID" />
      </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

After booting up my app with these changes, I can see an installation object being created on the Parse dashboard.

Now when I try to send a push via the dashboard and create an audience with platform Android, it says **'Your recipient count for this campaign can’t be empty.'**

What am I missing?

**EDIT 1:** I am able to send a push via the REST api. Still not able to send push via the web console.

Answer (score 0):

I had submitted this issue to the Facebook Developers page. This is the response that I received from the Facebook Engineering Team:

> This is a known issue with small recipient counts in the new dashboard. Unfortunately the engineering team doesn't plan to solve this bug in the new dashboard. Please use the old dashboard to send these push notifications.